# how to move marker along polyline in swift

Tags: swift

i had obtained the start and end locations through the json, but when i loop through to draw the animation ,it takes only last point of the loop and the marker moves in a straight line

func playAnimation() {

```
    let origin = "\(self.locationManager.location?.coordinate.latitude ?? 0),\(self.locationManager.location?.coordinate.longitude ?? 0)"
    let destination = "\(latitude),\(longitude)"


    let url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=\(origin)&destination=\(destination)&mode=driving&key=googleApi"
    print(url)
    let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    let session = URLSession(configuration: config)

    guard let requestUrl = URL(string   :url) else { return }
    let request = URLRequest(url:requestUrl)

    let task = session.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: {
        (data, response, error) in

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            if error != nil {
                print(error!.localizedDescription)

            }else{
                do {

                    if let json : [String:Any] = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? [String: Any]{

                        if let routes = json["routes"] as? [Any]  {
                            //print(routes)
                            if let route = routes[0] as? [String: Any] {
                                //print(route)
                                if let legs = route["legs"] as? [Any]{
                                    // print(legs)
                                    if let leg = legs[0] as? [String: Any]{
                                        // print(leg)
                                        if let steps = leg["steps"] as? [Any]{
                                            // print("steps:\(steps)")

                                            for step in steps {
                                                //print(step)
                                                let endLocation:NSDictionary = (step as! NSDictionary).value(forKey: "end_location") as! NSDictionary
                                                print("endLocation is : \(endLocation)")

                                                let endLocationLatitude = endLocation.object(forKey: "lat") as! CLLocationDegrees
                                                print(endLocationLatitude)

                                                let endLocationLongitude = endLocation.object(forKey: "lng") as! CLLocationDegrees
                                                print(endLocationLongitude)

                                                let startLocation:NSDictionary = (step as! NSDictionary).value(forKey: "start_location") as! NSDictionary
                                                print("startLocation is : \(startLocation)")

                                                let startLocationLatitude = startLocation.object(forKey: "lat") as! CLLocationDegrees
                                                print(startLocationLatitude)

                                                let startLocationLongitude = startLocation.object(forKey: "lng") as! CLLocationDegrees
                                                print(startLocationLongitude)
```

//                                                    let destinationLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(19.0178967, 72.8558875)

```
                                               let destinationLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(endLocationLatitude,endLocationLongitude)

                                                print("destinationLocation:\(destinationLocation)")


                                                let startLocationDestination = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(startLocationLatitude, startLocationLongitude)

                                              //self.updateMarker(startlocation: startLocationDestination, endlocation: destinationLocation)

                                               //self.updateMarker(coordinates: destinationLocation)
                                                CATransaction.begin()
                                                CATransaction.setAnimationDuration(5.0)
                                                self.marker.position = destinationLocation
                                                self.marker.map = self.mapView

                                                self.delay(2, closure: {})

                                                // Center Map View
                                                let camera = GMSCameraUpdate.setTarget(destinationLocation)
                                                self.mapView.animate(with: camera)

                                                CATransaction.commit()

                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }catch{
                    print("error in JSONSerialization")
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    })
    task.resume()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can move your marker using below code. You need to pass the position and the marker has to be present on the map. If marker is not there you first need to create it and then move

```
let position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 
self.locationManager.location?.coordinate.latitude ?? 0.0, longitude: self.locationManager.location?.coordinate.longitude ?? 0.0)
CATransaction.begin()
CATransaction.setAnimationDuration(1.0)
myMarker?.position =  position
myMarker?.map = mapView
myMarker?.appearAnimation = .pop
CATransaction.commit()
```

Comment: I already have a marker on the current location of the user, then placed a marker on the selected location. There after i need to move the marker from current location to the selected location. using the playAnimation() i got the start and end points, but looping through it not able to move the marker along the polyline path.

Comment: you will need to have the array of all the lat longs from start to end position and pass it to the  var position with time to play the animation

Comment: i had created the array of lat and long also passed to the position, but also the marker goes in the straight line. is there any possible way to show animation for each iterations of the for loop?

Comment: once you have the array for lat longs  say [ A, B, C, D, E] you move the marker first from A to B in say 1 sec then B to C in 1 sec and so on.

Comment: func moveMarker()
    {
        count = destinationArray.count
        print(count)
        //print(destinationArray[index])
        let nextPoint = destinationArray[index]
        print(nextPoint)
        
        CATransaction.begin()
        CATransaction.setAnimationDuration(5.0)
        self.marker.position = nextPoint
        self.marker.map = self.mapView
        self.marker.appearAnimation = .pop
        CATransaction.commit()
        //intially index is 0
        index += 1
        
        if index <= count-1 {
            self.moveMarker()
        }
    }

Comment: im new to swift. please help me out.. the above is the function im using to move marker, that is where im getting straight animation. please help me out